# Can't force django-celery to respect settings from settings.py

Tags: python, django, settings, celery, django-celery

here's an excerpt from my settings.py:

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest@localhost:6000//"
```

After

```
python manage.py celeryd
```

Celery starts up fine, showing:

```
 -------------- celery@karol-toshiba v3.0.12 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0xb6d01acc (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 2 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** -----
```

How to force it to use specified 'BROKER_URL' setting? Ultimately I would like it to use 'django://' backend url. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using the setting BROKER_TRANSPORT, BROKER_PORT or BROKER_BACKEND. 
BROKER_URL should suffice.